# Trouble Creating an IOS App Tutorial

Tags: ios

I'm having trouble creating an IOS App Tutorial. The quick little explanation of the app with pictures and 1 sentence explanations. I'm sure other people have had to make one of these before. How did you do it?

thanks,

Scott

Comment: This question is far too vague and no better than your previous question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18371765/can-you-recommend-a-good-iphone-app-tutorial-maker

Comment: You could make a youtube video tutorial and show it the first time a client opens the app

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you want this within the app or on your website?

For on the website: There's a lot of things you can do. Make a youtube video as Brandon suggested. Just launch the app and casually browse through it, while explaining what each part is. Or, you can gather screen shots of all the pages, then write a description of each page and the functionality of each element on the page.

For within the app: Create a prompt asking the user if they want a demo. If they choose yes, just put together a slideshow of screenshots of each of your apps views, and explain whatever you need to explain about it.

Comment: Good call on the slide show. I'm trying to do it in the App. Like something Tinder does. So it sounds like screenshots are the best way to do this. Thanks. If there is any more ideas, plz let me know.

Comment: @scottorn That sounds good, will do. And if the answer helped you out, that would be great if you could click the check mark next to it!